# Advice on the degree path

Tags: professional-education, career

I am currently in the first year of Computer Security at the university. But I have some doubts about the course. So I want to ask the professionals some questions :D

1. Is it better to lose a year and change to CS?
2. Do companies recognize a Computer Security course as a good course? Because I mostly see companies asking for a CS in the requirements.
3. Is it better to continue in Computer Security and then doing a Masters in CS? Or change right now to CS and do a Master in information security?
4. How is the outlook for jobs in security for the next years?

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you have your terms confused as I have never seen a Computer Security degree or job posting for such. I beleive by Computer Security you mean Information Security which usually falls under an Information Technology "IT" degree. A Computer Science "CS" degree is usually what programmers get. I have a bachelor's degree in IT with a specialization in Information Security and have been in the industry for over 10 years so based on my experience here are your answers:

1.Is it better to lose a year and change to CS?

If you want to be a programmer and not an IT Security professional then it would be better for you to switch. Most job postings that are looking for a bachelor's degree in Computer Science "CS" are programming gigs or maybe network administrators. If those types of jobs are what you want to do then I would say go for it.

2.Do companies recognize a Computer Security course as a good course? Because I mostly see companies asking for a CS in the requirements.

Please refer to my answer to 1. This really depends on the company and type of position you are applying for. I have seen job postings that are looking for an IT or CS bachelor’s degree. I believe this is because IT and CS degrees are pretty similar but they also have their differences.

3.Is it better to continue in Computer Security and then doing a Masters in CS? Or change right now to CS and do a Master in information security?

The nice thing about Master's degrees is you could do either. You could continue with your Computer Science degree then get a master's in IT Security. Honestly in this field I feel you’re better off getting a Bachelor's degree and getting some work experience under your belt then once you have done that taking certifications like Security + and eventually after you have enough work experience the CISSP. I had many internships and IT jobs while I was getting my IT Security degree. Real world experience will always get you some cred with most employers.

4.How is the outlook for jobs in security for the next years?

There will always be a need for cyber security professionals even more so now days. As long as we have computers and the internet it’s safe to say we will have job opportunities all over the world! 

If you'd like me to expand on any of my answers please let me know and feel free to ask as many questions as you like. I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for your post!I will probably continue with the Information Security degree to not lose a year of work and use that year to get that experience in. How did you find the internships?

Comment: Glad to hear your going to stick with it! You will have many opportunities to learn about how systems are managed and secured. My first internships were with IT security/support companies and a satellite communications company. Your school's career development center would be a great place to start looking for internships and you can also check job search sites like Monster and Dice. Ask you professors too! They might know of a company or two that is looking for interns. Even your classmates might be able to connect you with a position. Always keep a look out for new opportunities! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how passionate you are about security and if you are 100% sure it's what you want to do. If so, then great, I'm sure you'll do well at the course and have no problems getting a job at the end.

If not though, it might be a good idea to switch to Computer Science (I assume that's what you mean by 'CS'). In Computer Science you will study a far broader range of subjects, which at times will include security as well. You will find a lot more job opportunities will open themselves up throughout and after your degree.

Put it this way, if you do well in your degree but find out you do not like security anymore, it might be harder to get another job than if you just did Computer Science. Either way though, if you try hard enough, both degrees will easily land you a job in todays growing computer industry.